# need to find a pattern and extract that out

Tags: r, regex

My data frame has these rows

```
"110231 validation 108871 validation 85933"
"21102 validation 93442 21232 validation 73769 26402 validation 127221 26402"
"99763 99763 validation 99763 validation 99763"
"validation 199022 validation 122099 validation 12209 validation 199022 validation 199022 validation 122099"
```

Each string separated by coma is a new row , I need to extract out the first validation and number which follows it for each row. How can it be done ?

Expected output for each row should be

```
"validation 108871"
"validation 93442"
"validation 99763"
"validation 199022"
```

Comment: The question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt) to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the tour.

Comment: This is similar to your earlier question. Use a similar approach. Also you need to **accept and upvote answers**

Comment: the earlier one also didn't worked, I tried 3 different combinations along with suggested answers ,

Comment: It's because you show no attempt and provide data that is often close to impossible to work with. Please review how to ask a question to get more meaningful help.

Comment: Ankit, you are getting a relative flood of down-votes and close-suggestions, likely because of a long string of very-similar questions with little shown effort and/or resolution. If you want this issue resolved, I strongly suggest you double-down on one question (I think this seems the most detailed, I might be wrong), and provide feedback and details as quickly as possible. This is likely very frustrating to you, I understand, please listen to us and help us help you, via the guidelines and norms that are expected on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take one stab at this with two implementations.

First, I'll use a `character` vector. If yours is in a frame, replace it with `myframe$mycolumn`.

```r
v <- c("110231 validation 108871 validation 85933",
"21102 validation 93442 21232 validation 73769 26402 validation 127221 26402",
"99763 99763 validation 99763 validation 99763",
"validation 199022 validation 122099 validation 12209 validation 199022 validation 199022 validation 122099")
```

**Extraction of "validation number" matches**

```r
re <- gregexpr("validation [0-9]+", v)
re
# [[1]]
# [1]  8 26
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 17 16
# attr(,"index.type")
# [1] "chars"
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
# [[2]] ...
```

We can extract the matching substrings with `regmatches`:

```r
regmatches(v, re)
# [[1]]
# [1] "validation 108871" "validation 85933" 
# [[2]]
# [1] "validation 93442"  "validation 73769"  "validation 127221"
# [[3]]
# [1] "validation 99763" "validation 99763"
# [[4]]
# [1] "validation 199022" "validation 122099" "validation 12209" 
# [4] "validation 199022" "validation 199022" "validation 122099"
```

Now we have a list where each of your strings produced 1 or more matching substrings. Now we can just iterate over the list and get just the first element.

```r
sapply(regmatches(v, re), `[`, 1)
# [1] "validation 108871" "validation 93442"  "validation 99763" 
# [4] "validation 199022"
```

This should not fail, even if a string does not contain the substring pattern:

```r
v <- c(v, "nothing here")
re <- gregexpr("validation [0-9]+", v)
sapply(regmatches(v, re), `[`, 1)
# [1] "validation 108871" "validation 93442"  "validation 99763" 
# [4] "validation 199022" NA
```

where the `NA` indicates no matches but still preserves a place in your string vector.

**`gsub` only**

First, remove numbers/spaces up to but not including the first "validation":

```r
gsub("^[0-9 ]*(?=validation)", "", v, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "validation 108871 validation 85933"                                                                        
# [2] "validation 93442 21232 validation 73769 26402 validation 127221 26402"                                     
# [3] "validation 99763 validation 99763"                                                                         
# [4] "validation 199022 validation 122099 validation 12209 validation 199022 validation 199022 validation 122099"
```

Now remove anything after the first "number":

```r
gsub("([0-9])\\b.*", "", gsub("^[0-9 ]*(?=validation)", "", v, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "validation 10887" "validation 9344"  "validation 9976"  "validation 19902"
```